# Client application receiving duplicate reports

Tags: .net, http, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have an application that sends a report path and parameter collection to a Microsoft Reporting Services server.  One of these reports is very long running and when users try to generate reports within a few seconds of one another, one will receive a duplicate of the report requested by the second user.

This doesn't happen as a glitch, it is a consistent behavior that I can duplicate.  I can even run two copies of the application side by side and output their parameters in a trace statement, the parameters sent are distinct every time and yet the same report is returned to both clients.

Comment: Does your application control the rendering as well as sending the email?

Comment: Rendering is actually done on the webserver but can be done client side, problem is this report eats 900 megs of memory pretty quickly which is unacceptable for most users.  

I discovered yesterday however that the reports were distinct, but the report author was using shared variables in the custom code of the report.  I thought we knew better than that...  Thanks for the interest and spread the word, MSRS shared variables are asking for abuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment to mozy, shared variables in the custom code were the culprit.